# How to write a function to rename multiples columns at once?

Tags: r, function, dplyr, multiple-columns, rename

```
df1 <- df %>% 
  rename(newcol1 = oldcol1) %>% 
  rename(newcol2 = oldcol2) %>% 
  rename(newcol3 = oldcol3) %>% 
  rename(newcol4 = oldcol4) %>% 
  rename(newcol5 = oldcol5)
```

I am trying to write a function, which I just learned, that will do the same thing as above.

```
renaming = function(df, oldcol, newcol) {
rename(df, newcol = oldcol)
```

but then I am not sure how to do with the multiple columns.. 
any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: `df %>% purrr::set_names(~gsub('old', 'new', .x))` or `df %>% rename_all(~gsub('old', 'new', .x))`

Comment: @alistaire would you write c(oldcol1, oldcol2...etc)   for multiple columns?

Comment: No, the approaches above apply a function to the names of a data frame. The usual usage of `set_names` is to pass it a character vector of names, though, which would probably work in this case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using base R

```
names(df) <- c("newname1", "newname2", "newname3") # for all varnames
names(df)[c(1,3,4)] <- c("newname1", "newname3", "newname4") # for varnames 1,3,4
names(df)[names(df) == "oldname"] <- "newname" # for one varname
```

Using data.table

```
setnames(dt, old=c("oldname1", "oldname2"), new=c("newname1", "newname2"))
```

Using dplyr/tidyverse

```
df %>% rename(newname1 = oldname1, newname2 = oldname2)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `set_names` from the tidyverse package `purrr`.

Reproducible example:

```
> df <- iris
> df1 <- df %>% 
     purrr::set_names(c("d","x","y","z","a"))

> df1
      d   x   y   z          a
1   5.1 3.5 1.4 0.2     setosa
2   4.9 3.0 1.4 0.2     setosa
3   4.7 3.2 1.3 0.2     setosa
```